# CSS @media query to shift jquery banner is not working

Tags: css, media-queries

I want to shift a jquery banner with margin-top: 81px, only for small screens , the medium and extra small screens are looking great.

My media query is:

```
@media screen and (min-width:780px and max-width:980px) {
    .abr {
        margin: 81px 0px 10px -16px;
    }
}
```

but is not working for me please help me out of this...

Answer (score 0):

`min-width` and `max-width` are seperate queries, so they need to be made seperate with parenthesis:

```
@media screen and (min-width:780px) and (max-width:980px) { .. }
```